# if then statements with sys.argv in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to do a python script where I enter a argument into the command line.  The program is temperature.py so if I enter:

> ./temperature.py 56

sys.argv[1] = 56

Now the program is as such:

```
import sys

temp=sys.argv[1]
print temp

if temp < 65:
    print "Temperature is Cold"
else:
    print "Temperature is warm"
```

based on the above logic I would expect that if I entered in the prompt

> ./temperature.py 56

temp would be 56 which is less than 65, so I could have a response:

> "Temperature is Cold"

but I get the response:

> "Temperature is Warm"

no matter what temperature I put in the argument.
I still get the correct temp value that equals what the first argument is correct (56) so I am at a loss as to why the logic is malfunctioning in the if then statement.  How do I get the logic to work so that when I enter a temperature less than 65 (i.e. ./temperature.py 56) I get the response "Temperature is Cold" and if I enter a temperature greater than 65 (i.e. ./temperature.py 75), I would get the response temperature is warm?  Any ideas?

Comment: you need to convert your argument to `int` , `temp=int(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: You need to convert to an integer. `temp = int(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: @Totem you see his whole code -- he's using `sys.argv` to capture the arguments and isn't parsing them :)

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are strings, not integers. You're comparing `"56" < 65` which is `False`. Instead try:

```
# temperature.py
import sys

try:
    temperature = float(sys.argv[1])
except ValueError:
    print("Argument must be a number")
    sys.exit(1)
    # kick out with an error code

if temp < 65:
    # etc as you have it
```

Comment: You mean `sys.exit(1)`.  `return` cannot be outside of a function.

Comment: @iCodez whoops you're right. Been spending too much time in GUI apps and not much paying attention to CLI